How to fix 404 error for model while creating a store in ext js 7.7?
We are doing upgrade for our application from ext js 4.2 to ext js 7.7.
We have a model and we are trying to create a store using that model. But we are getting 404 error for the model. The same code is working with ext js 4.2 but now it is failing with ext js 7.7. Need help in fixing this issue.
Error Details:
GET https://9791859.app.netsuite.com/RAVI.Model.Weeks?_dc=1714733800105&page=1&start=0&limit=25 404 (Not Found).
Others stores which we created in the same way are working fine but no clue why only this store we are getting the issue.
Below is my model 'RAVI.Model.Weeks' which is extended from model 'RAVI.Model.SimpleList' which is further extended from 'Ext_Ravi.data.Model'.
Ext.define("RAVI.Model.SimpleList", {
  extend: "Ext.data.Model",
  idProperty: "id",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "id",
      type: "int",
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    {
      name: "name",
      type: "string",
    },
  ],
});


Ext.define("RAVI.Model.Weeks", {
  extend: "RAVI.Model.SimpleList",
  fields: [
    // id and name already inherited
    {
      name: "start",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "end",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "currentWeekNumber",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "previousYearWeeks",
      type: "string",
    },
  ],
});

Below is my store 'RAVI.Store.Pagination' which is extended from 'RAVI.Store.Base'
Ext.define("RAVI.Store.Base", {
  extend: "Ext.data.Store",
  autoLoad: false,
  buffered: false,
  constructor: function (config) {
    var extraParams = !config.extraParams ? [] : config.extraParams;
    if (config.url) {
      Ext.apply(config, {
        proxy: {
          type: "ajax",
          url: config.url,
          reader: {
            type: "json",
            root: "data",
            idProperty: "id",
            totalProperty: "totalCount",
          },
          appendId: false,
          extraParams: extraParams,
          ownerComponentId: config.ownerComponentId,
        },
      });
    }
    this.callParent([config]);
  },
});

Ext.define("RAVI.Store.Pagination", {
  extend: "RAVI.Store.Base",
  model: "RAVI.Model.Weeks",
  listeners: {
    load: function (store, records, successful, eOpts) {
      var myCombo = Ext.getCmp(RAVI.App.Panel.id + "-page-combo-box");
      if (myCombo) {
        myCombo.triggerDataCall();
      }
    },
  },
});

Below is the way we are creating a store
Ext.create("RAVI.Store.Pagination", {
  id: "ravi-style-trend-pl-page-combo-box",
  autoLoad: true,
  matchFieldWidth: false,
  data: {
    currentWeekNumber: "1",
    end: "1/6/2024",
    id: 1,
    name: "Wk 1: Dec 31 - Jan 6",
    previousYearWeeks: "52",
    start: "12/31/2023",
  },
});

Let me know if any one faced this and how to resolve it

Seems that the endpoint https://9791859.app.netsuite.com/RAVI.Model.Weeks calls does not exist on the server. If you try to make a GET request for example with Postman does it work?

In your application you try to load local data to the combobox.
In this case you have to add the following to your combobox:
queryMode: 'local'

Otherwise it will try to get the data from the server. As you are not defining a URL, and not defining a schema, the filename is usde. => /RAVI.Model.Weeks
If you want to load data from the server, you have to add an URL to the store.

tried adding queryMode: 'local' to my combobox but it is still the same @dinkheller

I edited my answer. If you are loading data from the server you have to add an url to the store
